# Hibernate save to db 31.12.2009 23:00:00.000000 instead of 1.1.2010

Tags: hibernate, datetime, jpa, jodatime

I have application with spring + jpa + hibernate. There are two joda date time fields. They are generate to database as TimeStamp(6).

The first one is set to DateTime()
The second one is set to 01/01/2010

If I check the saved values:
first one is set to LocalTime - 2 which it is probably UTC

**second one is set to 31.12.2009 23:00:00.000000**

WHY?????????

**Edit** according to comment by original author:

```
private void updateTimeStamps() 
{ 
  if (validFrom == null) { 
    validFrom = new DateTime(); 
  } 
  // if (validTill == null) { 
    validTill = new DateTime().withDate(2010, 01, 01); 
  // } 
}
```

But the difference of second one is UTC shift.

Comment: Please provide your code which sets the values. It's very likely an issue with UTC and locales.

Comment: private void updateTimeStamps() { if (validFrom == null) { validFrom = new DateTime(); } // if (validTill == null) { validTill = new DateTime().withDate(2010, 01, 01); // } }  But the difference of second one is UTC shift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```